# Mirth Connect: 2 Way ACK

Tags: mirth

I'm trying to figure out if it is somehow possible to setup Mirth to send 2 ACK back to the caller Application:
A) 1 ACK sent from Mirth to the caller when the transmission has been received from Mirth;
B) 1 ACK sent from Mirth to the caller after the channel is finished processing the message.

I know that Mirth can either be configured to send ACK before processing (case A above) or after processing (Case B above), but I could not find any way to send both.
Has anyone had experience in doing this?
Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mirth uses a single *responseMap* to store acknowledgement which is processed after all scripts. So, if you put anything there when a message is received, this Ack will be overridden with a new Ack placed into the same map at the end. And only the latter will be sent, which you've already experienced I guess.

If I'm correct, what you are trying to achieve is, first, to confirm that the message is received by a remote location (let's call it System B) and, second, is to confirm that the message successfully processed. If your client (System A) is capable to send a message to two endpoints at System B then you may create two receiving channels on the System B side, one of these channels sends ACK immediately after receiving the message and does nothing. The other channel processes the message and sends ACK in postprocessor.

There are other options, say, on System B side redirect an incoming message to another channel which forms Ack and sends it back to System A, but then System A should have a listener on its side.

Or, System B may have a receiving channel that sends Ack immediately, **routes** the message to another channel that is connected to its destinations, and remove that destination to prevent incoming message to propagate to that channel. The second channel processes the message and sends Ack back to the first channel. First channel resends that Ack back to System A. (I have not tested such configuration, so this is just an idea to overcome a single responseMap. It may not work.)

Comment: Thank you for your help, you directed me on the right track. 
It worked fine, I have a "dispatcher" channel listening to port 5000, which , acknowledges the receipt of the message, on the same IP/port and in the same connection, then forwards the message to a second channel using MLLP (on the same Mirth but on port 5001). 
This second channel, elaborates the HL7 message, waits for an  ACK (application ACK) coming from the application, and then sends the result of this second ACK to another IP/port (given to me by the HIS admin) on a new connection.